# bxSlider multiple reload calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

On my website I'm using bxslider to show dynamic content. This content is pulled through json when an user requests the data. When the content is changed, the slider.reloadSlider(); is called. This part works fine.

The problem is whenever you try to reload the slider when it is not done reloading, it will create a slider in a slider. The problem also occurs in the example on the bxslider website:
http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider

Click several times the 'Click to add a slide, then reload the slider' and you'll see what I mean.

My question is: how can i ensure that the next reload function only is called after finishing the previous reload function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Here's a workaround that I ended up using:

```
el.data('bxslider', el.bxSlider({
    ...,
    onSliderLoad: function() {
        el.data('bxslider-loaded', true);
    }
}));

function reloadSlider(el) {
    if( ! el || ! el.data('bxslider') || ! el.data('bxslider-loaded') )
        return;

    el.data('bxslider-loaded', false);
    el.data('bxslider').reloadSlider();
}
```

Basically, only reload the slider after onSliderLoad has been executed